# ASP.NET Core Individual User Accounts auth with no Azure

Tags: visual-studio, authentication, asp.net-core, identity

I am trying to create an asp.net core project (.net core 2.2) and I am selecting Individual User Accounts as Authentication. Problem is that I need to add Domain Name, Application Id and Sign-up or Sign-in Policy. I don't want to use Azure for this. How can I skip it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use ASP.NET Identity , choose `Store user accounts in-app` instead :

[image]

**Edit :**

For Web API application , there is only `Connect to an existing user store in the cloud` built-in template ,  which will allow authentication of users by way of JWT tokens such that Web APIs can be secured out of the box, and make it simpler to change authentication systems, e.g. from in-app Identity to Azure AD B2C or 3rd-party solutions like Identity Server.

You need to manually add ASP.NET Core Identity services if needed .

Comment: I dont see this option. Dropdown includes only one I posted in the image above

Comment: @pantonis , so that you are working with API application ,  for Web api, there is only connect to an existing user store in the cloud. See updated answer .

Comment: Really? Come on. future is SPA (Angular, React) why did the limit this?

Comment: @pantonis ,that is because  as for the API aspect, you usually need a token service to issue jwt token , and pass token to your api to create identity . Asp.net identity is not necessary for this scenario .

Comment: Asp.Net Core Identity is cookie based?

Comment: @pantonis , yes

Comment: Can I use the Asp.Net core Identity with jwt token?

Comment: You can use jwt token authentication in web api ,  during that process ,  you can read  user profile in database with asp.net identity provide functions and then sign-in user , or directly sign in user use [cookie authentication without ASP.NET Core Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Comment: I know but I was looking for a basic scaffold which includes this as Web Api

Comment: @pantonis , you need to manally add it . It's not supported currently with templete .